# Call a function into another using Action C#

Tags: c#

I have a function with a parameter and i want to call it as a parameter into another function using Action . this is the code :

```
    public void msg(string name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name);
    }

    public void CallMethod(Action<object> Function)
    {

        Function();

    }
```

it gives me an error when call `Method` function with msg parameter :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallMethod(msg("John"));
    }
```

I don't want to send the parameter in Method function like this :

```
    public void CallMethod(Action<object> Function)
    {

        Function("John");

    }
```

any help?

Comment: When you do `CallMethod(msg("Jhon"))` you are passing the **result** of calling `msg("Jhon")` into the `CallMethod` method. The result of `msg("Jhon")` is `void` - i.e. nothing. So it doesn't make sense. Question...why do you want/need to do this? If we understand the overall purpose of trying to create this `CallMethod` method, then we might be able to suggest a good way to achieve it. At the moment it doesn't seem to do anything useful, because you could just call the same method directly.

Comment: What is the purpose of `CallMethod`? You need parameter, if you don't want to hardcode `"Jhon"`, but why not calling `msg("Jhon")` directly?

Comment: for example, i want to create a function with Try - Catch for all functions and just pass the function name to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create generic method with parameter:

```
public void CallMethod<T>(Action<T> Function, T parameter)
{
    ...
    Function(parameter);
    ...
}
```

and use it like this:

```
CallMethod(msg, "John");
```

---

Another possibility is to pass delegate using lambda:

```
public void CallMethod(Action action)
{
    ...
    action();
    ...
}
```

the usage:

```
 CallMethod(() => msg("John"));
```